# Found a bag of pieces. Most unique to this bag is a cloth of yellow and gold stripes

Tags: part-identification

Most unique piece in this bag is a cloth of yellow and gold stripes. It has a hole in each of four corners. A number on the box that held this piece is 653999. What set does this go with?

Comment: Can you supply a picture of the bag?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the description on the cloth piece, the set should be the #31052 LEGO Creator Vacation Gateways https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=26243pb01&in=S